# List views inside scroll view in a fragment is working but responding very slow and showing ANR dialog

Tags: android, android-fragments, nested

I have eight swiping fragments on activity. One fragment is having two list views inside scroll view. These list-view's each item contain 4 edit-text and 1 image-view. I'm adding list-view's item to listview by pressing some button. Now when list-view size increases then it becomes slow and after adding 5 items it started showing ANR as well with slowness.

Answer (score 0):

> One fragment is having two list views inside scroll view.

Avoid that. `ListView` should never be put into a `ScrollView`. What are the images you put into the ImageView of the ListView ? What is their size ?

Comment: image size is `5kb only. If I avoid that then how to achieve functionality in which I want user to give freedom for giving name, direction etc. 4 parameters and photo options. means unlimited items of 4 edit-text and one image-view.

Comment: It doesn't work like this. The image is decompressed into a Bitmap. Only the size in pixels matters. If the image is 1000x1000 but compressed into a 200 kb file, the bitmap will still be 4 Mb.
Show the code of your adapter.